# What is my name, and where is my domain?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am blind
>   
> But I can feel.
>
> I feel the same up
>   
> As I feel down.
>
> I can go round but I'm not round,
>   
> I am strong and I am bound.
>
> I am found on the floor,
>   
> I can find 5 things not more.
>
> I have thousands of things,
>   
> But I can't fly, I don't have wings.

**To complete this riddle answer the following:**

- What five things can I find?
- What is my name?
- And where is my domain?

Comment: I was thinking a planet but only Pluto has 5 moons and it doesn't *really* fit

Comment: @Spacemonkey Good idea, but thats not it.

Comment: A foot fits pretty well (can't see, but can feel. You can put your feet up, or put your foot down. They go round on pedals. Strong enough to hold you up and bound by shoes. They're on the floor and have 5 toes). But the last two lines, although they technically fit, don't fit like a riddle should, so I assume I'm off the mark...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's:

> The tongue

Five things it can find:

> The 5 basic tastes, aka sweet, sour, salty, bitter and umami

Domain:

> The mouth

My reasons:

> - It's blind, but can feel food
>  - You can turn it around in your mouth
>  - One of the strongest muscles in your body, and bound to your mouth
>  - Found on the "floor", as opposed to the roof of your mouth
>  - Well, tongues don't have wings and can't fly

Comment: Tongues have thousands of taste buds.

Comment: @Eowhyn Good job you got it!

Comment: @Daedric Could you explain to me the "I feel the same up as I feel down" part though? I thought maybe you meant putting your tongue upside down but it doesn't really feel the same (at least to me), so I was wondering what you meant by that

Comment: umami? what is that? that doesn't fit

Comment: @ADG [Wikipedia article](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=umami)

Comment: @ADG You tongue, when flipped upside down (if you can do that) and touched, by say your finger, will feel as if you are touching the opposite side (or the side it would be if it was not upside down). I believe it is a Tactile Illusion but I maybe wrong. This is because the tongue never needed to develop a way of telling which way it was because naturally it cannot move upside down. (some people cannot do it).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

> Ant.

Five things:

> Five times their own weight.<sup>[[source](http://ant.edb.miyakyo-u.ac.jp/BE/Kingdom/2829/2829e.html)]</sup>

Domain:

> Eukaryote<sup>[[source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=domain+of+ants&oq=domain+of+ants&aqs=chrome..69i57.2671j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)]</sup>

Because:

> - Ants are blind.Compared to vertebrates, most ants have poor-to-mediocre eyesight and a few subterranean species are completely blind<sup>[[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant#Head)]</sup>
> - I believe they are symmetrical, both dorsal and ventral side.
> - Ants can go round
> - Ants are not round
> - They can sense things.
> - Ants are found on the floor.
> - They are strong (see the below point.).In experiments using ants of the Formica japonica species, the ants were found to be capable of lifting an object weighing 5 times as much as their own weight at the maximum in their mandibles<sup>[[source](http://ant.edb.miyakyo-u.ac.jp/BE/Kingdom/2829/2829e.html)]</sup>
> - Ants have thousands of tiny eyes within their main two eyes<sup>[[source](https://waegooksdiary.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/day-35-animals-and-ants/)]</sup>
> - Maybe ant's dont fly? And they don't have wings too.

Comment: Interesting Idea but it was Tongue sorry!

Comment: @Daedric I don't know but there's no reason why tounge should be preferred over ants. Give me one reason.

Comment: @ADG ant queens have wings and can fly

Comment: @Eowhyn That's just nitpicking, I can find mistakes in even the perfect.